# Is there a way to increase performance to suppress rows in Excel using Excel Add-in and C#

Tags: c#, excel-2010, excel-addins

I'm trying Excel Add-in to suppress rows which contains some values like this :

```
    private void FilterRows(Worksheet importedDataWorksheet)
    {

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range SearchRange = importedDataWorksheet.get_Range("E1", Type.Missing);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range n;

        do
        {
            n = SearchRange.Find("CRITERIA");
            if (n != null)
                n.EntireRow.Delete();
        } while (n != null);

    }
```

It works but it's extremely slow and I want to know if there is not another faster way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to look at different ways to read/write Excel in order to increase the speed as the overhead for any function call via Interop is very high.
I have used [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/42439) with a lot of success in the past to speed up the creation of sheets.